# Rewrite URL using .htaccess to shorten link

Tags: php, apache, url, url-rewriting

I am looking to be able to take the url

```
www.mydomain.com/profile.php?user=THEUSERNAME
```

and turn it into

```
www.mydomain.com/THEUSERNAME
```

Almost like Twitter.

I also want to be able to have it where i can go to

```
www.mydomain.com/THEUSERNAME
```

and it will go to the user's page, without changing the URL back to the long URL. I don't know how this is done and I also don't whether it will require .htaccess, PHP or possibly both.
Please help.

---

## SOLOUTION FOUND

---

## Inside your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ profile.php?user=$1 [L]
```

Also you are going to need to give the **absolute** URL to all of your CSS and JS files. For example, instead of having src="css/main.css" , you have to put src="http://yourdomain.com/css/main.css". The reason being is because if your url has a backslash (i.e **yourdomain.com/USERNAME/**) than it will think it is in the next directory and it will cause conflict. Absolute solves the CSS and JS problem.

## In the <head> of profile.php:

**NOT THIS:**

```
   <link href="css/allpage.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

THIS:

```
   <link href="http://yourdomain.com/css/allpage.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /profile.php?name=$1 [L]
```

That would work, http://yoursite.com/username (with or without trailing slash) will rewrite to http://yoursite.com/profile.php?user=username

Also you must use / based files (for `<script>` and `<link>`) or full URLs, if not you may get some 404 errors. I also suggest you to add a CDN and you can push that links vía CDN, one very good is maxCDN - 40USD the first TERABYTE!.

Good luck!

Comment: You don't really need the trailing slash but you *do* need to make sure that it's not a file or directory as that could lead to problems.

Comment: Ah, it's causing some problems. It's not working and it's causing errors with my files, it's unable to read files in seperate directories. Could this have to do with using an offline server (testing server WAMP), even though I have used REWRITES on this server before, and they worked perfect?

Comment: @Q.Sheets that's exactly what I meant, you just need to add a ? before $ on the link to rewrite and that would work, but it will be a very difficult thing to do.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time and helping me out. I have to tell you though this is still not working, in fact it just says "Object Not Found", almost as if the .htaccess file is untouched and you're searching for a dirrectory that doesn't exist.

Comment: Update---Solution found. Thank you guys for leading me on the right track.

Comment: @AlexSarnowski That was exactly what I told you on the first answer man. See the update.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
RewriteEngine on
# we're working the document root
RewriteBase /
# make sure requested item is not a file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# re-route everything that may be a username slug to the profile
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /profile.php?name=$1 [L]
```

Comment: This works perfectly though I might add another condition depending on what you need. `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` makes sure the request isn't a directory.

Comment: "not a directory" only makes sense if "DirectoryListing" is active. This is something you usually prohibit anyways. (which is why I left it out…)

Comment: Thank you for helping me, however I have to report that this is not working. It is also giving me an "Object Not Found" error, the identical error as the answer above. I had a rewrite that was working perfectly (when you did not have a trailing slash), but when a trailing slash was there, it was causing CSS & JS errors (probably because of absolute file location). So that is why I am seeking an alternative. Thank you for taking your time in trying to solve my trouble, I hope we can solve this problem.

Comment: Update---Solution found. Thank you guys for leading me on the right track